# How to Fix False Position Program

Tags: python

So for my program created, I ran the debugger and it just jumps right over the function I created and am not sure why...

```
import numpy as np 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def f1(x):
    return x*np.tan(x)


def f2(x):
    return np.cos(x)

ub = float(input("Enter a value for the upper bound of the function: "))
lb = float(input("Enter a value for the lower bound of the function: "))
tolf = float(input("Enter the tolerance for this function: "))

def myFP(lb,ub,tolf):
    xc = ((lb*f1(ub))-(ub*f1(lb)))/(f1(ub)-f1(lb))
    while abs(f1(xc)) > tolf:
        if f1(xc)*f1(lb) > 0:
            lb = xc
        else:
            ub = xc
        xc = ((lb * f1(ub)) - (ub * f1(lb))) / (f1(ub) - f1(lb))


print ("The root of the function is ", myFP)
```

Comment: Of course, your function never ran. you need to call your function like `myFP(ub, lb, tolf)`, also the format string is wrong.

Comment: How would I be able to fix those problems in able for it to work?

Comment: As Rocky Li said. You just add ans = myFP(lb,ub,tolf) before print. But before that, you need to add a *return xc* in you myFP

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about `myFP`, I guess that your debugger will go straight to the `print` line.

It is because you have defined your function, but never used it at this point.

You should call it using `myFP(arg1,arg2,arg3)`. 
However, you **really** don't wan't to use the name of global variables as arguments when defining your function (the `def` line) since it may be really confusing if it shadows the global variable or not...

Therefore, your function definition should be

```
def myFP(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    xc = ((arg1*f1(arg2))-(arg2*f1(arg1)))/(f1(arg2)-f1(arg1))
    while abs(f1(xc)) > arg3:
        if f1(xc)*f1(arg1) > 0:
            arg1 = xc
        else:
            arg2 = xc
        xc = ((arg1 * f1(arg2)) - (arg2 * f1(arg1))) / (f1(arg2) - f1(arg1))
        return xc
```

(Please note the presence of `return` at the end.)

With that said, if you want to use your function within a `print` call, you can do so by using

```
print ("The root of the function is ", myFP(lb,ub,tolf) )
```

Finally, to show it in a debugger, you should set a breakpoint at the first line of your function and step to the next line while running your `print` line or, better, using a *Step Into* feature on the `print` line.

Since `myFP` is called whithin the `print` call, the "call order" will be `myFP` -> `print` and you should be able to enter your function without any problem.

By the way, you might read some tutorial about defining functions in python such as [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) (Or any other) to be sure about your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Add the return to myFP:

```
import numpy as np 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def f1(x):
    return x*np.tan(x)


def f2(x):
    return np.cos(x)

ub = float(input("Enter a value for the upper bound of the function: "))
lb = float(input("Enter a value for the lower bound of the function: "))
tolf = float(input("Enter the tolerance for this function: "))

def myFP(lb,ub,tolf):
    xc = ((lb*f1(ub))-(ub*f1(lb)))/(f1(ub)-f1(lb))
    while abs(f1(xc)) > tolf:
        if f1(xc)*f1(lb) > 0:
            lb = xc
        else:
            ub = xc
        xc = ((lb * f1(ub)) - (ub * f1(lb))) / (f1(ub) - f1(lb))
    return xc #add this


print ("The root of the function is ", myFP(lb, ub, tolf)) #and this
```

I think that covers it.

Comment: Thank you so much...can't believe I have been overlooking something so simple this whole time

Comment: No prob. You can upvote this to help others with the same problem. =3